# How to send command to child process nodejs

Tags: node.js, child-process

I am making an application that handles java commands and want to send `java command` to my child spawn process how can i achieve this

```
  const {
    spawn
  } = require('child_process');

  // Start child process
  var child = spawn('java', ['-server', '-Xms1G', `-Xmx${document.getElementById('ram').value}G`, `-jar`, `${jarname}`], {
    cwd: `${jarfolder}`
  });

  child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    $("ol").append(`<li>${data}</li><br>`);
  });

  child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    $("ol").append(`<li>${data}</li><br>`);
  });

  child.on('error', (error) => console.log(`error: ${error.message}`));

  child.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
    if (code) $("ol").append(`<li>Process exit with code: ${code}</li><br>`);
    if (signal) $("ol").append(`<li>Process killed with signal: ${signal}</li><br>`);
  });
```

demo code

example i have a button that calls a function and

```
function test(){
      var command=document.getElementsById("command").innerHTML;
      
      // send the command to terminatal
```

Comment: I seems from the documentation that `spawn` doesn't offer a communication channel. Have you tried with [fork](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processforkmodulepath-args-options) and then communicate with the child processes using `child.send(...)` / `child.on('message', ...)`?

Comment: This should help you with the steps of communicating between NODE JS processes, for catching data from a forked process in JAVA i am not sure. [CHILD FORK](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a/#:~:text=be%20avoided%20otherwise.-,The%20fork()%20function,-The%20fork%20function)